# Is it possible to set Brotli compression level dynamically based on the request headers in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, brotli, ngx-brotli

I'm using Brotli for response compression, and doing this in Nginx using [nginx-brotli module](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/brotli/).

I would like to set the value for `brotli_comp_level` dynamically based on the request headers, so that clients on slow networks could request higher compression. How can I achieve this?

I tried to no avail:

```
http {
  ...

  brotli on;
  brotli_comp_level 6;
  brotli_types *;

  if ($http_x_brotli_high_quality) {
    brotli_comp_level 11;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the stock/packaged Brotli module from NGINX Plus.

You can, however, custom compile (not recommended for production) with the following [pull request](https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli/pull/58) integrated.

Or, if the budget allows, use the [`nginx-module-brotli`](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/modules/brotli/) module package from [NGINX Extras](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-extras), which has the aforementioned pull request integrated into the packages. This option requires a CentOS/RHEL machine and maintaining a paid subscription with GetPageSpeed.